# While upgrading from pimcore 6.6 version to pimcore 6.9.6, facing migration error

Tags: php, symfony, pimcore

pimcore migrating from 6.6 version to 6.9.6 version

Updated version in composer.json file 6.9.6  then executed this command

```
COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer update
```

Getting below errors:

```
Migration 20201222101114 failed during Execution. Error Unknown database type json requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySqlPlatform may not support it.

Unknown database type json requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySqlPlatform may not support it.

Script Pimcore\Composer::executeMigrationsUp handling the post-update-cmd event terminated with an exception

[RuntimeException]                                                                                                                            An error occurred when executing the "'pimcore:migrations:migrate -s pimcore_core -n'" command:                                            
                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                             
   Pimcore Core Migrations                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                             
  Migrating up to 20210310115115 from 20201207132025                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                             
    ++ migrating 20201222101114                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                             
  Migration 20201222101114 failed during Execution. Error Unknown database type json requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySqlPlatform may n  
  ot support it.                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                              
  In AbstractPlatform.php line 443:                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                             
    Unknown database type json requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySqlPlatform                                                              
     may not support it.
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running?  It may be that it isn't supported.

Comment: im using mysql 5.6.46 version.
But when i read pimcore 6.9 document. its mentioned that mysql v 5.6.4 supports

Comment: Not sure about that, but json is only supported since MySQL 5.7.8. Also pimcore 6.9 is no longer supported (EOL just over 2 years ago), so ideally you should also look at using a newer vesion if possible.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for quick response. I will try to install 5.7 version of mysql and check in pimcore 6.9 version supports or not

Comment: @NigelRen, when im trying to install mysql 5.7 version it everytime installs 5.7.3 , not the v 5.7.8,
when i mention specific sub version like 5.7.8, it throws me error saying this 
E: Version '5.7.8-1ubuntu18.04' for 'mysql-community-client' was not found
can you please guide me how to install mysql 5.7.8 specific version on ubuntu 20.04 ?

Comment: Migration 20201222101114 failed during Execution. Error Unknown database type json requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySqlPlatform may not support it.

still im getting this issue, after installing mysql 8 version , can anyone tell me what is the cause and how to resolve?